# XOR of Three Integers

Tags: arithmetic, binary, binary-operations

How would you prove the following:

Given three non-negative integers $a, b, c$; if $a \oplus b \oplus c = 0$ then $(a - k) \oplus (b - k) \oplus (c - k) > 0$ for any $0 < k \leq \min(a, b, c)$ ? (with $\oplus$ I mean bitwise XOR or nim-sum)

Regards.

Comment: Does the $> 0$ mean $\neq 0$ or is there some binary representation of $-1$ in this unbounded binary format?

Comment: There is no change if $k=0$

Comment: Is $k$ allowed to be negative? If not, the result fails for $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: No, $k > 0$.  The problem deals only with nonnegative integers.

Comment: Doesn't "non-negative" mean $\ge 0$?

Comment: I was referring to numbers $a, b, c$ and the new values after subtracting $k$.

Comment: Suppose you have a Nim position consisting of three heaps, and it is (in normal play, not misère) a win for the first player.  If you remove $k$ stones from each of the heaps, then the resulting Nim position will be a win for the second player.

Comment: @GEdgar Usually that equivalency is proven the other way, IIRC - that is, OP's lemma is one of the steps in showing that $a\oplus b$ is actually the value of the nim position $(a,b)$.

Comment: For $a = b$ we get $c = 0$. In this case $min(a,b,c)$ would also be $0$ which contradicts $0 \lt k$. Should we therefor assume $a \ne b$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough outline for a 3-step proof.

**Step 1** Rephrase to remove the subtraction, and the restriction on $k$.  The original claim is equivalent to: for any $a', b', c'\geq 0$, and $k \geq 0$, if $a' \oplus b' \oplus c' = 0$, then $(a'+k)\oplus(b'+k)\oplus(c'+k) \neq 0$.

**Step 2** Rephrase in terms of binary operations, more straightforward to work with.  The claim is equivalent to: for any $a',b' \geq 0$, and $k > 0$, we have $(a'+k) \oplus (b'+k) \neq (a \oplus b) + k$.

**Step 3** Prove this last form directly.  As a warmup, start with the case $k=1$.  In general, the smallest nonzero bit of $k$ will give a place in which $(a'+k) \oplus (b'+k)$ and $(a \oplus b) + k$ differ.